# Using Ransack to sort attributes for parent of parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I know how to use Ransack's awesome `sort_link` method for parent attributes, but when I extrapolate the same logic to the attributes of the grandparent, it's not working (I can click the link, just no sorting happens).

Hierarchy goes like this: `Signup has_many Request has_many Transaction`. I'm searching in from the Transaction perspective.

**Controller code:**

```
def index
  @q = Transaction.ransack(params[:q])
  @transactions = @q.result.includes(:request => :signup)
end
```

**View code:**

```
<th><%= sort_link(@q, 'requests.signup.email', "Email") %></th>
<th><%= sort_link(@q, 'requests.pickupdate', "Pick up date") %></th>
<th><%= sort_link(@q, 'requests.returndate', "Returndate") %></th>
```

Incidentally, the search code (e.g., `:request_returndate_eq`) is fine, it's just the sorting that's not working.

**Model code:**

```
class Signup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :requests
end

class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :signup
  has_many :transactions, dependent: :destroy
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :request
end
```

**Console output**

On first click to sort ascending (though with any click it always produces a 200 response, even though the view doesn't actually change)

```
Started GET "/admin/transactions?q%5Bs%5D=requests.signups.email+asc" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-07 13:40:16 -0700
  Processing by TransactionsController#index as HTML
    Parameters: {"q"=>{"s"=>"requests.signups.email asc"}}
    Rendered layouts/_flash.html.erb (0.6ms)
      (0.4ms)  SELECT "transactions"."name" FROM "transactions"
    Transaction Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "transactions".* FROM "transactions"
    Request Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests"  WHERE "requests"."id" IN (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50)
    Signup Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "signups".* FROM "signups"  WHERE "signups"."id" IN (4, 5, 1, 2)
  Rendered transactions/index.html.erb within layouts/application (74.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 85ms (Views: 81.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

Comment: Can u please try `'requests.signups.email'` and see what happens.

Comment: Forgot to mention I tried that, doesn't work either. By the way the `requests.pickupdate` and `requests.returndate` aren't even working

Comment: Could you please post your model definitions. All three of them.

Comment: instead of `includes` try with `joins`

Comment: No doesn't work either

Comment: Can you please post what you get in the console. What are the get request parameters and what does the controller do with them, or try to do.

Comment: @San, ok I just added that as well

Answer (score 0):

You can using [delegate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) to avoid parent or parent expression in view.

Model

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :request
  delegate :email, to: :request, prefix: true
end
```

Transaction View code:

```
<th><%= sort_link(@q, 'request_email', "Email") %></th>
```