# Ransack sorting for Associations doesn't work

Tags: sorting, ransack

I need to sort data in tables with Ransack `sort_link` method when I use association.
I have:

**MODELS**

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tasks
...
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to  :deal
...
end
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
...
@search = Deal.where(assigned_to: @user_id).where.not(stage: [6, 7]).search(params[:q])
@deals = @search.result.joins(:tasks).where(assigned_to: @user_id).where.not(stage: [6, 7]).uniq
...
```

**_DEALS.HTML.ERB**

```
...
<th style="width: 15%" class="text-center"><%= sort_link @search, 'tasks.due', "Задача", {}, { :remote => true, :method => :get } %></th>
...
```

The result is that sorting doesn't work, however we have positive signals from server:

**SERVER LOG**

```
Processing by DealsController#index as JS
Parameters: {"q"=>{"s"=>"tasks.due desc"}}
Rendered deals/_deals.html.erb (21.0ms)
Rendered deals/index.js.erb (24.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 24.0ms | ActiveRecord: 9.7ms)
```

Have reviewed dozens of ransack-related issues, including [Using Ransack to sort attributes for parent of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593225/using-ransack-to-sort-attributes-for-parent-of-parent?rq=1) and [Rails sorting associations with Ransack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065592/rails-sorting-associations-with-ransack)
but they have no reply so far.

I suspect I'm misdoing something from https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack. Had several smart guesses but unfortunately they didn't work.

THX.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [github issue](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/13), try `sort_link @search, 'tasks_due'...`

Note that it is `assocation_name`, not `table_name.name` as in documentation